# GitLab CI Pipeline: Pipeline cannot be run

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I can't find out why the GitLab CI Pipelines for my Repo won't run. I have a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and the feature enabled, but the pipeline won't run. Also if I try to trigger the pipeline manually I get the following error back.

```
Pipeline cannot be run.
Pipeline will not run for the selected trigger. The rules configuration prevented any jobs from being added to the pipeline.
```

[image]

The CI feature is enabled.

[image]

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

npm-run-build:
  stage: build
  image: node:19
  only: 
    - main
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-build
    paths:
      - dist/
  script:
    - cp .env.example .env
    - npm ci
    - npm run build-only
deploy-dist:
  stage: deploy
  image: fedora:latest
  only: 
    - main
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://example.com
  needs:
    - npm-run-build
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-build
    paths:
      - dist/
      
  before_script:
    - dnf install -y openssh-clients
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan -t rsa example.com > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    # create remote project dir if not available
    - ssh thomas@example.com "mkdir -p /home/thomas/example.com"
    # upload project files
    - scp -prq . thomas@example.com:/home/thomas/example.com
    # restart the container
    - ssh thomas@example.com "cd /home/thomas/example.com && docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d"
```

Thank you!

Comment: On which branch are you trying to run your pipeline?

Comment: oh my god, I'm blind again! 

Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

As D Malan pointed out in the comments, I have restricted the runs with `only` to the `main` branch. But the branch name is actually `master`

So I just changed the rule form `main` to `master` and now it is running

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct so it will have the GREEN V

Answer (score 1):

I've spent an hour trying to figure out what's wrong, seemingly I did everything right, but here:

```
  only:
    refs:
      - develop
    variables:
      - ...
```

I had a non existent variable in the `variables` section.

Answer (score 0):

GitLab changes its CI templates from time to time.

If your `.gitlab-ci.yml` was created based on an older version of a GitLab template, search for the latest version of the template [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/tree/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates), click *History* and see if it's changed recently. If it has, modify your `.gitlab-ci.yml` according to these template changes.

For example, I have just found out that [they had changed](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/commit/beabc7d164276a8bb35c2b497a0c4dc0dc824e3c)

```yaml
image: image-name
```

to

```yaml
default:
   image: image-name
```